# How to receive ICS Wi-Fi hotspot enale/disable via broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, wifi

I would like to know if we can receive information via broadcastreceiver (onReceive) to know that if user enable/disable "Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot" (Settings->Wireless &Networks->Tethering & portable hotspot).

Since I found that I am not able to use android.net.wifi.WifiManager to monitor this at ICE Cream version.

Does anyone can share some hints to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use action named "android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" for monitoring state changes on WiFi-AP.

http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#132